# CSS Nested Floats & Clears Behaving Inconsistently

Tags: css, nested, css-float

Please see [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vycfw/9/) for reference.

Most of us are fairly familiar with a simple technique to get CSS Colunms (2 divs side-by site) which involves floating one and pushing the other over using margin & `width:auto` followed by one of many clearing techniques. **(Exibit A @ [jsFiddle Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/Vycfw/9/))**.

This Technique works fairly well and works nicely with all forms of clearing I know personally:

- `clear: both` div at bottom of container
- `overflow: hidden` for the container
- Clearfix for the container

However the simple implentation of this works great when you know the width of the left element and want the right element to fill up the rest of it's container.

This technique works great in reverse too (`float: right` and using `margin-right`) with the caveat that you must put the floated (right) element first in the container for IE to render correctly. **(Exibit B @ [jsFiddle Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/Vycfw/9/))**

However, I've noticed a problem when we deal with nested clearing. (Aka Clears inside one of the colunms).

Once I put a clearing container inside the un-floated colunm **(Exibit C & D)** I notice some strange behavior in WebKit & Gecko browsers. The *clearing element* is getting caught on the outer float and clears the float from it's parent.

This does not happen when the master float is to the left. **(Exibit E)**

Is there a way around this, I'd like to continue using `float: right` on the known-width column if possible, this seems a bit strange that the one works and the other doesn't.

Also, strangely enough, this isn't a problem in IE9, (but is in IE 6-8).

For reference, this is the output of the jsFiddle as rendered by Chrome 17.0.963.46 on Windows 7 64bit:

[image: Render]

Any Ideas?

---

**Edit**: I should note that wrapping the inner float with `overflow: hidden` seems to work, but it has it's own complications (such that it basically breaks anything with relative/absolute positioned components, DHTML Dropdowns. etc and isn't always a possible solution.

Comment: What's stopping you adding a width to the left column?

Comment: @mikos: I don't always know the width of the left, sometimes it needs to flow to it's container, but the floated element (in this case: right) is a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something important here... but does this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/8Hnjg/

Comment: That's Exhibit E (The working example). I need to use a `float: right` if possible in this case, as the left part needs to flow to fill it's container (horizontally) and the width isn't determinate. The problem comes from the fact that the exact same technique just in reverse produces drastically different results.

Comment: do you know the width of the inner float: right?  maybe you could float it left and position: relative to get it over to the right.

Comment: The inner float isn't the problem, it's the clear for that inner causing the content below to clear below the OUTER float.